# Python DataFrame Replace '+'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

From a SQL Dataframe, I've imported a list of phone numbers, I tried to strip all all other characters from the list.

```
FixSet['reeeee'] = FixSet['home_phone__c'].replace('[^0-9]+.-', '', regex=True)
```

It gets most almost everything, but:

```
print(FixSet['reeeee'])

1449    +15178818
1450    +17208417
1451    +19313494
1452    +14194661
1453    +15634517
1454    +13072865
1455    +15415561
1456    +19416856
```

Can't seem to figure out, out of every configuration, to get rid of the plus sign.

Comment: Put those characters in a char class: `'[^\d]|[+.-]'`

Comment: How does the column look like before replace? If you need to replace everything but numbers, use FixSet['home_phone__c'].replace('\D+', '', regex=True)

Comment: @COLDSPEED it worked!

Comment: @MethJordan Try Vaishali's answer, just use `r'\D+'`

Comment: @Vaishali both worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape the plus sign `'[^0-9]\+.-'`

Answer (score 1):

By default `+` (or `*`) matches greedily, so the pattern given in the question will match upto the last.
By appending `?` after the repetition operator (`+`), you can make it match non-greedy way.

```
FixSet['reeeee'] = FixSet['home_phone__c'].replace('\[^0-9\]+?.-', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.